# is the wso2 cep HA doc running the nodes on a single server

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

Is the doc in the ha documentation running both nodes on the same server? why are all the ip addresses 127.0.0.1 and H2 config referring on node2 referring to node1's filesystem path.

[The doc](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/07/high-availability-choices-for-wso2-complex-event-processor-3.1.0/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to demonstrate HA functionality, so that users can try this on their local machine, Do use the appropriate machine host/ips and ports when appropriate.

Suho

Comment: Thanks. Had to change the ips and use mysql for the registry db on an external server. Having H2 didnt seem like a valid use in multinode environment